# Read empty file and the output is symbol

Tags: c, file

i am new in c. So in my university, i just learn about file in c. and i got a task. If i put an empty file in my project directory, and read it. The output are symbols (i dont know what symbol it is). So here is the code, please help

```
player dota[100];
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("soal09.txt", "r");
if(fp == NULL)
{
    printf("Error Opening The File!!\n");
    return 0;
}
else
{
    while(!feof(fp))
    {
        fscanf(fp, "%[^ ] %d %d\n", &dota[idx].name, &dota[idx].score, &dota[idx].num);
        idx++;
    }
}
fclose(fp);

do
{
    enter();
    menu();
    printf("Input your choice [1..5]: ");
    scanf("%d", &choose); fflush(stdin);

    if(choose == 1)
    {
        system("cls");
        enter();
        printf("%-20s %-15s     %s\n", "Player Name", ": Average Score", ": Number of Playing");
        printf("====================================================================\n");
        for(int i = 0; i < idx; i++)
        {
            printf("%-20s %-15d     %d\n", dota[i].name, dota[i].score, dota[i].num);
        }
        printf("\nPress Enter to Continue...");
        getchar();
    }

getchar();
return 0;
```

}

and the output is ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠ -858993460
Thank you ^^

Comment: See [why while (!feof(file)) is always wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/62576)

Comment: And the alternative to `while (!feof(file))` is to *check the return values of your function calls*, which in fact you should do for **every** function call whose return value conveys status information about which you care.

Comment: ╠ is 0xCC in codepage 437, and [MSVC fills 0xCC to uninitialized memory to help debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/q/370195/995714). That means you've accessed uninitialized memory. You can find tons of questions about ╠ and 0xCC here on SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The end-of-file indicator that is checked by `feof()` is only set after a previous file I/O operation has failed. You must attempt an I/O operation to find out if you have reached the end of the file. So, with an empty file, your code attempts to read the file, the end-of-file indicator is set, no values are read into the first `struct`, but `idx` is incremented, so it looks like you have added data for a player. But the fields of the first `struct` are uninitialized, so you are seeing garbage. Also note that `dota[idx].name` is presumably an array of `char`s, so it decays to a pointer to `char` when passed to `fscanf()`. Using `&dota[idx].name`, as you have, is wrong, though it might appear to work. It does cause the compiler to emit a warning, and you should have these enabled (I *always* use at least `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic`).

[You should not use `feof()` to control file I/O loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong?s=1|2.5997). One simple solution is to use the return value of `fscanf()` to control the loop:

```
while(fscanf(fp, "%[^ ] %d %d\n",
             dota[idx].name, &dota[idx].score, &dota[idx].num) == 3) {
    idx++;
}
```

This will only update a `player` `struct` if three assignments are made by the call to `fscanf()`. But, the problem with this simple solution is that it doesn't handle malformed input well. If a line of the data file is missing a field, the `struct` will be incorrectly filled, and the loop will terminate, even if there are more lines in the file to read. Also, since no field width is specified for the string conversion, a long name could crash your program.

A better solution uses `fgets()` to read the lines of the file into a buffer, and then uses `sscanf()` to extract the information from the buffer:

```
#include <string.h>        // for strcpy()

...

char buffer[1000];
int line = 0;
char temp_name[100];
int temp_score, temp_num;

while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp)) {
    ++line;

    if (sscanf(buffer, "%99[^ ] %d %d\n",
               temp_name, &temp_score, &temp_num) == 3) {
        strcpy(dota[idx].name, temp_name);
        dota[idx].score = temp_score;
        dota[idx].num = temp_num;
        ++idx;
    } else if (buffer[0] != '\n') {
        fprintf(stderr, "Bad input in line %d\n", line);
    }
}
```

Here, a generous `buffer` is declared to accept a line of text from the file, and temporary variables are declared to hold the values to be stored in the `struct` fields. I have chosen a size of 100 for `temp_name`, but this should match the size of the string array in your actual `struct`. Note that the string conversion in `sscanf()` has a field width of 99, so that at most 99 non-space (not non-whitespace, and why aren't you just using `%99s` here?) characters are matched, leaving space for the `'\0'` to be added.

`fgets()` will return `NULL` when it reaches the end of the file, so the loop will continue until that happens. For each line that is read, a `line` counter is incremented. Then `sscanf()` is used to read data into the temporary variables. The value returned from `sscanf()` is checked to be sure that 3 assignments were made, and if so, then the data is copied into the `struct`, and `idx` is incremented. Note that `strcpy()` is needed to copy the string from `temp_name` to `dota[idx].name`.

If the value returned from `sscanf()` indicates that something other than 3 assignments were made, there is a check to see if `buffer` holds an empty line. If not, an error message is printed to `stderr` providing the line number of the bad input in the file.

A couple of further comments. Your `do` loop appears to be missing the associated `while()`. And you use `fflush(stdin)` after the `scanf()` inside the `do` loop. `fflush()`is meant to flush output streams. The behavior of `fflush()` on input streams is explicitly undefined in the C Standard (ISO/IEC 9899:2011 7.21.5.2/2), though I believe that Microsoft deviates from the Standard here. Nevertheless, you should not use `fflush(stdin)` in portable C code. Instead, use something like this:

```
int c;

...

scanf("%d", &choose);
while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
    continue;                  // discard extra characters
```

This code reads characters from the input stream until either a `'\n'` or `EOF` is reached, clearing any characters left behind by the previous call to `scanf()` from the input stream.

Comment: Thanks a lot!. it really helps! ;)